# Leaderboard with different lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I was just wondering, what is the best word based on this rule: (distinct letters in a word)^2 / (total letters in the word). So i started with some basic stuff

```
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader (FILE_PATH);
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        List<string> words = new List<string> ();
        List<double> points = new List<double> ();

        while ((line = SR.ReadLine ()) != null) {
            short unique = (short)line.Distinct ().ToArray ().Length;
            short total = (short)line.Length;
            double value = (15 * Math.PI * Math.Pow (unique, 2)) / total;

            words.Add (line);
            points.Add (value);

            counter++;
        }

        int Index = points.IndexOf (points.Max ());
        Console.WriteLine ("best: " + words [Index] + " points: " + points [Index]);
    }
```

But i'd also like to have a leaderboard with the "best" words and the relative points. I have an idea in mind that would require different lists to find out the word having the points, but is there a more simple and fast way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a *single* `Dictionary<string, double>` (*word* and its corresponding *value*) instead of *two* zipped `Lists`:

```
Dictionary<string, double> points = File
  .ReadLines(FILE_PATH)
 //.Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) // you may want to filter out empty lines
  .Select(line => new {
     word = line,
     unique = word.Distinct().Count()
     total = word.Length })
  .ToDictionary(item => item.word, 
                item => 15 * Math.PI * item.unique * item.unique / item.total);
```

So you can easily implement a leader board with a help of *Linq*:

```
  var TopTen = points
    .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value)
    .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key)
    .Take(10)
    .Select(pair => $"word: {pair.Key} points: {pair.Value}");

  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, TopTen));
```